# TFS CAL User License - Separate Networks

Tags: tfs

So here's the grey area situation.

We have two separate networks which are meant to be kept separate for development purposes and would like to set up TFS servers on both of them.  I already know that each server will require it's own license but what about the users?

I've read the whitepaper and still am unclear on the situation.

Do we have to purchase 2 sets of CALs per individual user (one per network) or, since they are going to be the same users on different networks, is it okay install/use the same instance of the CAL on two different networks?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about licensing policies of a particular vendor.

Comment: I don't understand?  I only asked the question in the TFS areas since that is what it applies to.  I'm still new-ish to stackoverflow so please excuse my ignorance but where should I have posted?  How can I present my question so it's appropriate?

Comment: Your question is not appropriate for any stackexchange site. It's an appropriate question to ask Microsoft. FYI, there are no "areas" - there are just tags.

Comment: I have contacted Microsoft and will again in the future.  The answers/support were either unclear or in the same grey area.  I am exhausting my options.  I just wanted to ask other professionals who may have more personal experience on the issue or plain know more.

Thank you for the advice.

Comment: No problem. But please read the [faq] to learn why this is not a forum where you can "ask other professionals" about their "personal experience"

Comment: This leaves me conflicted because I have read the FAQ and understand the issue but would not like to remove the posting as it may help someone else in the future.

Comment: I expect that the question will be closed and deleted. It won't help anyone.

Comment: Personally I don't understand why questions about TFS licensing are closed.  The SO rules specifically state that questions which "generally cover software tools commonly used by programmers" are on-topic.

Comment: "tools" questions are only on-topic if they directly relate to writing computer programs. All Stack Overflow questions must be about writing programs. If you look at what's the faq - you can't just match on the ticks - you also have to not-match on the crosses :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So long as it's 2 networks but one company, then each user only needs one CAL.  Also Server's do not require CAL's, they require Server Licenses which you receive 1 per MSDN sub.

So you need 2 Server Licenses, and 1 CAL per user.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I figured, but wanted to make sure before pulling any triggers.  I will word my question better in order to avoid future confusion.